# The resource cannot be found. WCF .svc file

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis

I am making a WCF service.

System Config: Widnows 7, ASP.NET 3.5, IIS 7.0
Server Config: IIS7, ASP.NET 3.5

It works fine on my system, but when i deploy this on the server i get following error

 **The resource cannot be found.**

when i try accessing my .svc file. Please help me out in this.

My server is with GoDaddy, so i have no control on the server. I have to do everything in my code only. Please help.

Comment: Are you sure you're accessing the correct URL for the .svc file? That sounds like a 404 error to me. Keep in mind the `relative` portion of the svc path may look different in the published server than while developing in visual studio. Can you post more details on the error?

Comment: yes..i am quite sure. There is one scripts folder also, which has some .js files. I am able to access those.  I am pasting the link, you see it yourself.
http://www.askmaps.in/testing/service/AdMapService.svc (service link)
http://www.askmaps.in/testing/service/Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js ( .js link)
Please check this link. I will paste more details, just tell me. But please help me..

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue when try to deploy my WCF rest service to Windows Server 2008 R2 x64.
The interesting thing that the service works fine on Windows Server 2008 R2 x86.

After a few days digging I found that installing [.NET Framework 4 update](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2468871) solves the issue for me.

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add the .svc extension in your config. Check this blog [Running WCF on GoDaddy](http://www.edoverip.com/edoverip/index.php/2009/01/30/running-wcf-on-godaddy/)

Comment: Hi i have already done that. I am pasting the tags, i have written in my web.config
<buildProviders>
            <add extension=".svc" type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceBuildProvider, System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
          </buildProviders>

Comment: Also, i came across all those 3 errors (mentioned in blog), and my web.config holds all those. But even then i am getting an error... Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the problem in your case but the solution might help someone else.

I ran into this error message because I somehow had a virtual directory mapping that was overriding my service URL.

Ex: `localhost/ServiceName/MyService.svc/` was actually mapped to an invalid location.

So when I'd try to access the actual .svc in the ServiceName folder the virtual mapping would override it and give me that error.

To fix, select "Default Web Site" (or where ever you have yours) in IIS, hit "View Applications", and remove the faulty virtual directory mapping.